# Little problem with xscale and tikzducks

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, scaling, tikzducks

I would like to mirror an image of `tikzducks` which has the `book` option.

Using `xscale=1` works, but the title of the book is not well mirrored.

Does it exist a way to adjust it without doing it manually with `\rotatebox`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Initial image:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Image with \verb|xscale=-1| option:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Image with \verb|xscale=-1| and \verb|\rotatebox| to adjust the book title 
    inclination (what I'd like to achieve):

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
        \duck[book=\rotatebox{40}{\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}}]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The book is a node , and nodes are only transformed (rotated etc) if you use the transform shape key. But naturally this will also mirror the text, so you need reflectbox to get it back::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Initial image:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Image with \verb|xscale=-1| option:

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,transform shape]
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,transform shape]
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\reflectbox{\TeX}}]
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been fixed in version 0.6 of the `tikzducks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Initial image:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.5}{\TeX}]
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

now gives

[image]