# Flip node without flipping text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am trying to flip a node without flipping text inside. I tried using `\rotatebox`, but it won't help in flipping. Is there any way to do so? I have attached minimal code example below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,shape=trapezium,trapezium left angle=40,trapezium right angle=-40,minimum height=1in,minimum width=1in,trapezium stretches=true,xscale=-1] at (5.38in,-5.38in) { text here};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output:

[image: After flipping]

Comment: give angles as `-40` and `40` instead ?

Comment: That is fine for this example but there are some shapes for which this won't be possible, so flipping is the only option. And I don't want text to get rotated with that. How to achieve it?

Comment: Create the flipped node with `\phantom` text to fix its size and place the non flipped text (with another node) on its center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformations don't apply on the nodes, unless you want it like you do. To solve this problem, you just have to build a path on which you will place two nodes, the first one having the width of the text but made invisible, the second one the text itself.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (5.38in,-5.38in) node [draw,shape=trapezium,trapezium left angle=40,
 trapezium right angle=-40,minimum height=1in,minimum width=1in,
 trapezium stretches=true,xscale=-1]{\phantom{text here}}
 node {text here};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

output:

[image: flip-node]

Answer (score 1):

I had [a similar problem with `tikzduck`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398256/little-problem-with-xscale-and-tikzducks). It's enough to reflect the node text (with `\reflectbox`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node [
    draw,
    shape=trapezium,
    trapezium left angle=40,
    trapezium right angle=-40,
    minimum height=1in,
    minimum width=1in,
    trapezium stretches=true,
    xscale=-1
    ] at (5.38in,-5.38in) 
    {\reflectbox{text here}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]